# how do I turn a computer into a real safe router?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router, wireless-router

I have an old hp that i installed ubuntu on and I was wondering how I can turn it into a real router. By real router I don't just mean broadcast the internet but use security software, configurations, and all the stuff normally found on a real router. What are the steps i need to take? I dont have 2 NIC's in it just one but I do have a wireless usb that I can just stick into it.

Comment: Using an old PC as a router can be a fun experiment and a rewarding learning experience, but I also like to remind people that it can often be financially and ecologically unwise as an old PC probably uses far more electricity than an embedded home gateway product.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of linux distros that are tailored specifically for use as routers/firewalls

look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions

There are also BSD based options as well.